# NHibernate collections: Update doesn't cascade

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Currious behavior here. If I create a new HashCode, save the HashCode, then add a Transaction to the Transactions collection, the cascade is failing on Update. The Transaction object doesn't appear in the DB, and, curiously, the HashCode object's properties aren't updated either!

I have no idea what could be causing this. Here is the relevant mapping:

```
<class name="MyProject.HashCode, MyProject" table="HashCodes">
    <id column="Id" name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="User" column="UserId" class="MyProject.User, MyProject" />
    <property name="Hash" />
    <property name="PasswordHash" />
    <property name="InitialValue" update="false" />
    <property name="CurrentValue" update="true" />
    <property name="ClaimedDate" />
    <property name="ClaimId" column="RowGuid" generated="insert" />

    <bag name="Transactions" table="Transactions" cascade="all" inverse="true">
      <key column="HashCodeId" />
      <many-to-many column="Id" class="MyProject.Transaction, MyProject" />
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="MyProject.Transaction, MyProject" table="Transactions">
    <id column="Id" name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="HashCode" column="HashCodeId" class="MyProject.HashCode, MyProject" />
    <property name="AmountCharged" />
    <property name="AmountBilled" />
    <property name="PreviousBalance" />
    <property name="Memo" />
    <property name="TransactionDate" generated="insert" update="false" />
</class>
```

Here is the test case that is failing, too, in case it's relevant:

```
[Test]
public void TransactionsCascadeWhenUpdatingHashCodes()
{
    var user = TestFactory.CreateUser();
    var hashCode = TestFactory.CreateHashCode(user);

    var transaction = new Transaction
    {
        AmountBilled = hashCode.CurrentValue,
        AmountCharged = decimal.Subtract(hashCode.CurrentValue, decimal.Multiply(hashCode.CurrentValue, 0.03M)),
        HashCode = hashCode,
        Memo = "This is a test",
        PreviousBalance = hashCode.CurrentValue,
        TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    hashCode.Transactions.Add(transaction);

    // Now try to save it.
    var hashCodeRepository = new HashCodeRepository(Session);
    hashCodeRepository.Update(hashCode);

    // Now see if that transaction is good to go
    Assert.IsTrue(hashCode.Transactions[0].Id > 0);

    // See if that transaction got persisted.
    var loadedTransaction = Session.Load<Transaction>(hashCode.Transactions[0].Id);
    Assert.IsNotNull(loadedTransaction);
}

// The repository method that is called...
public virtual void Update(TObj obj)
{
    CurrentSession.Update(obj);
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: What does hashCodeRepository.Update do? If you are using the Unit Of Work pattern, you don't normally need such a method ... unless update is attaching the entity to the session. If the entity is attached, just flush the session. Are you doing that?

Comment: Looks like you are misunderstanding the purpose of session.update - this is for reattaching a detached entity, not for propagating changes.

Comment: You also have a problem with your last Assert, Load will not do what you think it will.  Load creates a proxy object for you which will only go to the database to hydrate when you access one of its properties, it will then throw an exception OR hydrate properly - it will never return null.  You need to use Session.Get<Transaction>(...)

Comment: @Iain I create a transaction in my SetUp method for my test cases and I rollback the transaction in the TearDown method. Note that even if I commit the transaction in the TearDown method the object still doesn't cascade.

Comment: You can use SaveOrUpdate() instead of Update() - this will also persist new objects.

Answer (score 5):

You are not flushing the session anywhere.

Comment: That is outside the scope of this test case...I begin a transaction in the SetUp method and rollback the transaction in the TearDown method. Note that even if I commit the transaction the changes don't propagate.

Comment: For most generators, no changes are persisted until the session is flushed. As UpTheCreek said, Session.Update(alreadyPersistentEntity) is a noop.

Comment: Calling Update does not hit the database. I suggest you read this http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html.

Answer (score 0):

Change your update method to the following:

```
public virtual void Update(TObj obj)
{
    using (ITransaction tx = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```